# How to use filter with object or convert object into array then use filter

Tags: arrays, angular

I fetched the data using Promise, and after that I want to filter the res, but I can't filter it because the return res is an object, not an array.

I tried to convert it into an array, but I couldn't.

```
  getData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.serivceService.getData().toPromise().then((res) => {
    console.log("res",typeof res);
    res.filter((item) => {
     item.name === "Leanne Graham"
    })
  });
```

I don't know what is the correct way. Can I deal with the object directly or convert it to an array before applying the filter?

Comment: please share the data you get for this http request in the 'network' tab in the browser devtools

Comment: I added the picture

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok, sorry I thought he wanted an image of the network tap to see the data that was returned, so I just updated the post and added the image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's in `this.serivceService.getData()` method, but the correct way is to use `httpClient` service, and there is a generic type you can add and the data will map to it automatically, for example:

```
 this.httpClient.get<User[]>('/users')
```

so in that case your data returned map into array of users and then you can filter it as you wish